# ASP.NET Core MVC - using multifactor push auth with Microsoft Authenticator

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-factor-authentication, authenticator

I am writing a web app in C# for .NET Core which also should have integrated two-factor authentication and external logins.

I succeeded at integrating multifactor authentication using TOTP (TimedBased One Time Password). This means that every time I log in, I should fill in a code from my smartphone. Because I'm developing, I log in 100 times a day. So, I am getting tired of unlocking my phone, opening the authenticator app and filling in the verification code.

In our company, we make use of Azure Active Directory with two-factor authentication, but in Azure AD, we use two-factor push auth. If we try to log in, you get a push notification at your phone and then you could deny or grant access. That doesn't need filling a code.

I found documentation for the app Authy from Twilio to use Authy for push notification, but in the company I work, we are Microsoft-minded and everyone in the office uses the Microsoft Authenticator app, so my software should use this app also.

I found documentation for Authy, however, I didn't find this for the Microsoft App, while we use this also in Azure.

To enable two-factor authentication, you should scan the qrcode from the PC. The code of my app is

```
otpauth://totp/[Appname]:admin@admin.nl?secret=[Secret key]&issuer=[AppName/Companyname]&digits=6
```

The QR code of Azure AD, to let login RDS with 2fa has the following URL:

```
phonefactor://activate_account?code=[code]&url=[url]
```

I found that PhoneFactor is an application to enable MFA, using push notifications, but I can't find how to implement this in my own web app.

Is this possible? And where should I look to?

Comment: I don't think Microsoft has an API for push two-factor. That's just for their own Microsoft Accounts. Anything else has to use OTP. Authy *does* have an API for this, and as far as I'm aware, is the only service of its type that does.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Right, I also thought that maybe only Microsoft could use this. Indeed I looked to Authy, but the whole company is microsoft minded, so they won't like if everyone should download the Authy app too. Then I will still use OTP, because that works also, only it's a bit irritating to fill in the code if you are logging in 100 times a day :P

Comment: To be clear, if you're using Azure AD, I think push will still work. It just needs to be a Microsoft service. Not sure about that 100% though.

Comment: Yes, in-company we use Azure AD with push auth, but now I would use this too for my web app. That's te problem right now.

Comment: have a look at this. `https://github.com/beemdevelopment/Aegis/issues/25`. We can not generate code without making call to microsoft api